# Iterated and Double limits exisitence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital, sequence-of-function

The existence of the double limit of a multi variable function at a point implies that the iterated limits will also be the same in value and exist, given that we know that that the individual single limits of the function, in x and y exist.
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (\alpha, \beta)} f(x,y) = L\implies \lim_{x \to \alpha} (\lim_{y \to \beta} f(x,y)) = \lim_{y \to \beta} (\lim_{x \to \alpha} f(x,y)) = L$$
Given that we know that :
$$\lim_{x \to \alpha} f(x,y) \mbox{  and  } \lim_{x \to \beta} f(x,y) \mbox{  exist  } $$
My question is why is this so? Why is the existence of single limits necessary for the above mentioned implication.
As an example take the following function:
$$ f(x,y) = xsin(1/y) $$
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = 0 $$
$$\therefore \mbox{    as expected :} $$
$$ lim_{y \to 0} (\lim_{x \to 0} f(x,y)) = 0  $$
$$ \mbox{but} $$
$$ lim_{x \to 0} (\lim_{y \to 0} f(x,y)) = \mbox{Does not exist} $$

Comment: by single limit i mean lim(y - > 0) f(x,y) only, i think you have it confused with double limit, i.e lim ( x,y - > 0,0) f(x,y) , the double limit exists, so like you said all paths should exist, but the one of the iterated limit does not exist @NinadMunshi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the iterated paths doesn't exist because **the line $y = 0$ is not in the domain of $f(x,y)$**. So, $\lim_{{y}\to{0}}f(x,y)$ doesn't exist. But, we can still travel through every other path within the domain of $f(x,y)$ and the limit remains $0$.

You're not meant to follow paths outside the domain to check if a limit exists.